# Adding an object to one to many relationship ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having trouble adding an object to associate class.
the parent class, user, has a has_many relation with the ad class.
When i try to access user's has_many object ":ads" from the ad controller, it returns me an "undefined method ads" exception. I am posting my model and my controller code below. Please help me on this issue.

user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :ads

    has_secure_password

    has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "50x50#" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
    validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

    def self.searchID(query)
        where("id like ?", "#{query}") 
    end
end
```

ad model

```
class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user

    scope :orderNewestFirst , lambda { order("id DESC") }

    has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100#" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
    validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

    def self.search(query)
        where("title like ?", "%#{query}%") 
    end

end
```

Ad Controller

```
class AdController < ApplicationController

    layout false
  before_action :confirm_logged_in

    def index
        @ads = Ad.orderNewestFirst
    end

    def new
        @ad = Ad.new()
    end

    def create
      @find = session[:user_id]
      @user = User.searchID(@find)

        @ad = Ad.new(ad_params)

        if @user.ads << @ad    #***this is where the error is occuring***
            flash[:notice] = "Ad created Successfully"
            redirect_to(:controller => 'user' , :action => 'index')
        else
            render('new')
        end
    end

    def show
        @ad = Ad.find(params[:id])
    end

    def ad_params
      params.require(:ad).permit(:title, :category, :description , :priceRange, :avatar )
    end
end
```

**EDIT**

Here are my migrations for User and Ad

User Migration

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration

    def up
        create_table :users do |t|
            t.string "firstName" , :limit => 50 , :null => false
            t.string "lastName" , :limit => 50
            t.string "email" , :null => false
            t.string "password" , :limit => 30 , :null => false
            t.integer "rating" , :default => 0
            t.string "location" , :default => "Lahore"
            t.timestamps null: false
        end
    end

    def down
        drop_table :users
    end
end

#user = User.new(:firstName => "" , :lastName => "" , :email => "" , :password => "" , :rating => "" , :location => "")
```

Ad Migration

```
class CreateAds < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def up
        create_table :ads do |t|
        t.references :user
            t.string "title" , :null => false
            t.string "category" , :null => false
            t.text "description" 
            t.string "priceRange" , :null => false
        t.attachment :avatar
        t.timestamps null: false
        end
      add_index("ads" , "user_id")
    end

    def down
        drop_table :ads
    end

end


#ad = Ad.new(:title => "" , :category => "" , :description => "" , :priceRange => "")
```

The error that i get..

[image]

Comment: What is the table name for `ad` model?, and does `ad` model have `user_id` column in it?

Comment: Please post your full error stacktrace.

Comment: @PramodShinde , i am using references instead of user_id.

Comment: @Pavan Please see the attached image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `User.searchID(query)` returns multiple user records (a relation object), not a single one.

If you change it to `User.searchID(query).take`, it fetches only a single record, and the error vanishes.

I don't know what value `session[:user_id]` holds, but looking at your `users` table, this would simply be an integer ID? In that case, there isn't much sense in the current approach. I'd recommend something like this:

```
def create
  @user = User.find(session[:user_id])

  # Rest of create method
end
```

The `User.find` method looks for a user record with that exact ID, and will return a single record straight away. This is one of the most common ways to fetch records using Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how like query with `id` is working for you, In postgres it doesn't

```
def self.searchID(query)
    where("id like ?", "#{query}") 
end
```

You don't need above method you can find user directly by id as

```
@user = User.find(session[:user_id])
```